# Live Agent button in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning

Is this possible to develop a lightning component which display Salesforce live agent chat button? Can someone please give me guideline?

I tried putting the Javascript code in the controller but the button doesn't display at all.

I need to integrate the lightning component on Salesforce community which is based on Koa template.

Answer (score 0):

The lightning component will not allow you to make a callout to the external third party system hence you may run into certain issues if you directly make callout .

If you are on winter 16 ,there is a [neat article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000214820&language=en_US) which shows how you can add live agent for the templates but unfortunately Spring 16 will stop allowing us to edit templates via site.com builder and hence right approach is to go via the community builder as you figured .

Spring 16 has provided a way to call third party scripts via Head Tag and i guess some part of script should go there

Also there is a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QbvhRS03eQ) that shows Chat component for the Community templates and I assume SFDC has built it .I guess its not documented yet .I am reaching out to Product Team to see where I can grab some documentation .

[image]

Appexchange from salesforce is about to come but here is the initial package I got from success community if anyone wants to give a try

https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t61000000Tmnp

Comment: Did you hear anything from the Product Team on implementing LiveAgent to a community component?

Comment: Here is a component .This is not official and not secure as it has not gone through sec review .But give a try with this https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t61000000Tmnp